# How to get the time when a mysql trigger was created or last updated?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

We have a trigger in our mysql database which on update affect some data in database. But for some calculation we need to know when this trigger was first created and when it was updated last. Is it possible to get this data from information_schema or any where else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. There is a column CREATED in the schema for triggers, but it is unused (always NULL) at the present time:

> The following columns currently always contain NULL: TRIGGER_CATALOG,
>   EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG, ACTION_CONDITION, ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE,
>   ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE, and CREATED.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem but accepting as the best answer as no one comes with a solution. But isn't it a common case when someone write a trigger and after a while find its not doing as it should and want to reverse the changes by observing the rows affected so far? Hope the created column become useful in next mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about triggers in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont see any helpful column in trigger table

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I don't know what datatype you are using for created.

But for example, I use DATETIME.

Before insert, and you just need to use SET:

**Create:**

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE 
  TRIGGER yourtriggername BEFORE INSERT ON yourtablename 
    FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.created = NOW();
END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

**Update:**

```
DELIMITER $$ CREATE  
    TRIGGER yourtriggername AFTER UPDATE ON yourtablename
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
        SET NEW.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where.....yourconditions;   
END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked for. I wanted to know when the DBA created/updated a particular trigger in my db.

Comment: @FRX Sorry. But your wrote like this in question, 'But for some calculation we need to know when this trigger was first created and when it was updated last. ' Here you wrote when this trigger was first created. Not anything related to DBA. So I thought you mean only trigger. ;-)